# Do all functions in a c++ program's main function get called regardless of error?

Tags: c++

Let's say i have a program that executes `void foo()` from `main()`. What happens if `foo` has lets say a vector out of range exception. Then after `foo()` inside the `main()` there is a function called `bar()` will bar be executed?

```
void main() {
foo() //exception in this function
bar() //will bar be called?
}
```

Assuming that foo() has no manually constructed system exit calls.

Comment: If there is no exception handler, the application will terminate.

Comment: Did you try? With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C++ compiler? Did you read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) ?

Comment: IDK about all other exceptions, but out of bound exception is thrown due to OS not giving you access to memory, and that one is bound to terminate program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uncaught C++ exception will terminate the program. Often with a stack trace but that is up to the implementation.

So no, in your example `bar()` will never be called.

Update: In some situations the optimizer could inline both functions and move some code from `bar` to the top of `main`. You would only see this in a debugger though, because anything with side effects cannot be moved like that.